# Updating a File in R by adding a column/vector

Tags: r, csv, data-wrangling

Is there any way that I can update an existing .csv file by adding a column/vector that I have scraped from the web. I have a webscraper that pulls COVID-19 data and I am trying to create a file that has positive cases in columns and each column is the list of cases for a day in each county (x-axis is counties, y-axis is date). I have toyed around with many different ideas at this point and seem to have hit a roadblock. I'm fairly new to r so any ideas would be appreciated!

Packages I am Currently Using/Planning to Use:

library(tidyverse)
library(funModeling)
library(Hmisc)
library(rvest)
library(ggplot2)

CODE:

```
#writing the original file

positive <- data.frame(Counties= counties_list, "06/12/2020"= positive_data)
positive[is.na(positive)]= 0
positive = positive[-c(76),]
write.csv(positive, "C:/Users/Nathan May/Desktop/Research Files (ABI)/Covid/Data For 
Shiny/Positive/Positive Data.csv")


#creating the new vector and updating the existing file with it

datap <- read.csv("C:/Users/Nathan May/Desktop/Research Files (ABI)/Covid/Data For 
Shiny/Positive/Positive Data.csv")
positive_data = positive_data[-c(76),]
datap$DATE <- positive_data
```

NOTE: The end goal is to create a ShinyApp that displays bar charts for postives, recoveries, and deaths by day in each county. This is the data wrangling portion.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Is there a particular reason you need the data in this "wide" format, with a column for each date? Given the followup stuff you're going to do (the charting etc) I think it would be easier if you used a "long" format, a frame with four columns: County, Date, Metric, Value. Metric would be one of ("Positives", "Recoveries", or "Deaths"), and value would have the value for that metric, for the county, for the day. This would give you one csv to update (instead of separate csvs for each metric), and the update would be adding rows instead of adding columns.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if you are going to use the tidyverse, use `tibble` instead of `data.frame`. Tibbles are [the Tidyverse version of data frames](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/).

Next, be aware of the structure of your data frame. The way you create your data.frame now (and later probably your tibble) you get a variable "Counties" and one additional variable for each day. That means that you will have to add columns as time passes (the opposite of what you described: Moving along the x axis (along columns) will move along dates while moving along the y-axis (moving along rows) will move along counties). It's possible but I think a bit unconventional. You might want to initialize your data frame with one column for each county and an additional variable called "date". Then whenever you get new data you can add a row in your dataframe instead of a column (so you're "adding a new case" instead of "adding a new variable").

To actually add the row you will have to load the data as you do in your code, create the new row (or column, if you insist) and then "glue" it to the rest of the data.
Depending on how your data looks you can create a single row dataframe using `tibble_row()` with the same countries as variable names as you have in your main data frame and then glue them together with `add_row(datap, your_new_row)`. Alternatively, if you want to add the row only using position and not column names, you can have the new row as a vector and use `rbind()` instead of `add_row`.

If you persist with the "one variable per date" approach there's column equivalents (`add_column` and `cbind`) for both these functions.

Hope this helps, Cheers